# Sumif criteria with for loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, sumifs

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer

i = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Rows.Count + 1
j = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Columns.Count 
k = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Rows.Count - 7 

For l = 2 To j
    Cells(i + 2, l).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(9, l), Cells(i, l)), ">0", Range(Cells(9, l), Cells(i, l)))
Next l
```

Hi, I am trying to use sumif function in vba. The point is to do this in loop, which depends on the number of columns. I do not actually now what is wrong here, but I think that probably there is something with criteria I took. I want to sum all cells with number higher than 0 and not sure how to write this.

Comment: but inside your `SumIf` the Range `Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(i, 2))` is not advanced with the `For` loop, it's always column B. Did you mean `Range(Cells(l, 2), Cells(i, 2))` ? or something similar ?

Comment: It's ofc like this, sorry:
`Cells(i + 2, l).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(9, l), Cells(i, l)), ">0", Range(Cells(9, l), Cells(i, l)))`

Comment: still not working, just to be clear

Comment: are you trying to sum only values in ranges if they are >0 (only positive values) ?

Comment: try my code below, see if it works as you intended

Comment: yes, I want only positive values

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If in your `SumIf` you are using the Range you are comparing with the Criteria (`>0`) also as the Range to sum, there is no need to add it inside the `SumIf` as the third argument.

You could go with the code below:

```
For l = 2 To j
    Cells(i + 2, l).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(9, l), Cells(i, l)), ">0")
Next l
```

Comment: @Cezary it does for me, what values do you have for `j` and `i` ? I think you are not getting the values you think from your `PivotTable` data table

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function. No need to use "*" for comparing

```
Cells(i + 2, l).Value = Aplication.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(i, 2)), "> 0", Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(i, 2)))
```

Comment: still not working, there is not even error appearing, just code is not executed

Comment: try using ">0" instead of "> 0".